# About the return value is reference

Tags: java

Look at this example：

```
public class Leaf{

    Leaf increment();

    public static void main(String[] rags){
        Leaf x = new Leaf();
        x.increment().increment();
    }
}
```

I simplified it from **Thinking In Java**. When I use the reference `x` to call the method `increment`, the return value is a reference, but it is never assigned. Why is it able to call the second increment directly?

If that line is like this I can easily understand:

```
Leaf temp = new Leaf();
temp = x.increment();
temp.increment();
```

Comment: Because increment() returns a Leaf object, and you can chain method calls.

Comment: If you don't use `temp` (or if `increment` returns `this`), the second example is pretty much equivalent to the first one, so if you understand one you should understand the other.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I see chain method calls in JQuery first.Perhaps I do not understand chain method calls,why can it use this object directly without reference?

Comment: Do you understand why `int x = 1+2+3;` works? Because this (very) roughly follows the same logic as that. `1+2` gives you `3`, but you don't need to assign that to another variable to be able to add another `3` to it.

Comment: @Dukeling you helped me a lot,and I do not know the detail of this.Perhaps it’s related to the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`increment()` returns an object which is the instance of Leaf class, and every object which is the instance of Leaf can have that method invoked on it. You do not have to assign it to a variable, it is preserved in memory already, and following method call will work on the reference returned from first `increment()` method call.

You can isolate it like this: `(leaf.increment()).increment()`, when the first method is done, it will return new leaf object which will have the second method invoked on it. So it is in fact something like this `(returnValueOfFirstIncrement).increment()`

It's your choice whether you want to assign result value of first method call to a variable or not, but the object will be returned anyway, and you can work with it even without assigning it to a variable.

My wording might not be the best, but I tried to explain it as simple as possible.

EDIT;

The person who commented your question had given a good example why this works.

`1 + 2 + 3` is equal as `myInteger1.add(myInteger2).add(myInteger3)`.
*Keep in mind that java Integer does not contain `add` methods as such, it is implicit, so to understand this example, imagine myIntegers are all instances of imaginary MyInteger class which has such methods.*

`myInteger1.add(myInteger2)` will return value equal to `new MyInteger(3)`. This will be preserved somewhere in memory and reference to that in memory preserved object will be returned. So myInteger1.add(myInteger2) is equal to the return value of that snippet which is `new MyInteger(3)` which makes this look like `(new MyInteger(3)).add(myInteger3)`. The compiler will resolve methods one by one, and use return values of each to resolve the next one in case such as this, where methods are chained.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I’m sorry that I’m stubborn,I think my question is why can the function like `leaf.increment()`becomes that `returnValueOfFirstIncrement`?I do not know the process of function return,maybe it’s because I didn’t learn compiler principle.

Comment: No worries mate, nothing to be sorry about. I edited my answer. Hopefully, it is more understandable now. We were all once at the point where we just started coding/learning a new language and feel free to ask any questions you may have. StackOverflow helped me a lot, the community is great and everyone here is willing to help one another.

Comment: Your reply help me a lot about how **1+2+3** works.But I want to know how can the compiler resolve this method chaining?For example,Compiler see like this code `leaf.increment()`，compiler is going to invoke to this method,why can it becomes a return value such as a object,if return value exits?I don’t know the details,this puzzled me a night.

Comment: @zzkyeee It is just how the language is defined. If you call a method and the method does return something you can immediately work with this returned object and call a follow-up on it. As the exact return type is always pre-defined by the method (and thus known to the compiler), it also knows which methods will be appropriate for follow-ups and which not. It reads `leaf.increment().increment()`, and checks the return type of `leaf.increment()`. It is `Leaf`, thus a second `increment()` call makes sense, it accepts it and starts execution.

Comment: @Zabuza is correct, increment() returns Leaf object, it's defined so in method's signature, and every method has to define its return type in the signature. So when you type leaf.increment(), java knows it will return a new Leaf object, and it allows you to work with it by chaining another method on it. Imagine computer object which has its components. This allows you to do following `computer.getCPU().getSocketType()`. `getCPU()` will return CPU type object, which can invoke method named `getSocketType()`. The end result of such chain will be socket type of computer's CPU.